# object comparison not working in HashSet

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I was writing equals and hashcode implementation inside my employee class

```
public class Employee {

    private Integer eid;

    private String name;

    private Integer annualSalary; 

    private String location;

    public Employee(Integer eid, String name, Integer annualSalary, String location) {
        super();
        this.eid = eid;
        this.name = name;
        this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
        this.location = location;
    }

    //setter and getters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Employee secondemp = (Employee) obj;

        boolean equalsComparison = this.getEid() == secondemp.getEid() 
                && this.getName().equals(secondemp.getName())
                && this.getAnnualSalary() == secondemp.getAnnualSalary() //this condition is returning as false
                && this.getLocation().equals(secondemp.getLocation()); 

        System.out.println("equals=>"+equalsComparison);

        return equalsComparison;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 31;
        hash += this.getEid().hashCode();
        hash += this.getName().hashCode();
        hash += this.getAnnualSalary();
        hash += this.getLocation().hashCode();

        System.out.println("hashcode=>"+hash);
        return hash;
        //return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ""+this.eid;
    }
}
```

After adding same employee objects inside hashset class.

```
    private Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<>();   
employeeSet.add(new Employee(101, "Ankit Agarwal", 10001, "Uttar Pradesh"));
employeeSet.add(new Employee(101, "Ankit Agarwal", 10001, "Uttar Pradesh"));
employeeSet.add(new Employee(101, "Ankit Agarwal", 10001, "Uttar Pradesh"));
employeeSet.add(new Employee(101, "Ankit Agarwal", 10001, "Uttar Pradesh"));
employeeSet.add(new Employee(101, "Ankit Agarwal", 10001, "Uttar Pradesh"));
```

Comparison on the equals method is not working.

However, if I changes the datatype to primitive i.e. **int**, then comparison is working fine.

After debugging more on it, this condition is returning false on equals method

```
            && this.getAnnualSalary() == secondemp.getAnnualSalary()
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You are comparing Integers with `==`. Use `equals`

Comment: if you use an IDE you can let it generate the code for hashCode and equals. if you don't use an IDE i would recommend doing so

Comment: thanks @Eran i forgot by using wrapper classes I need to use equals method

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a wrapper class in the first place!

Comment: but why this condition is working `this.getEid() == secondemp.getEid() ` since eid is also has wrapper class

Comment: @Ankit `Integer == Integer` returns `true` if `Integer` is within the bounds of a `byte`.  Otherwise, it will return `false` for two different objects.